# Extjs4 drag and drop zones error with IE,FF and Safari

Tags: firefox, google-chrome, drag-and-drop, extjs4, cross-browser

I have multiple grids in a panel. The base grids have data in them and can be dragged and dropped between each other. All the grids in the panel should be able to drag and drop between each other. This works perfectly in chrome but not Firefox, IE, or Safari.

In IE,FF and Safari the grids with data in them will drag and drop between each other w/o problem. They will not between the empty grids. I tried adding data to the empty grids but that wasn't the problem. Firebug also errors when using it with Extjs so any bugs i get are from a different dev tool. I have reinstalled all of those browsers and that is not the answer either. Im stuck...

**edit** I found out in chrome the viewconfig for my dragdrop groups are set but it doesnt set in the other browsers

This is my base grid with data in it.

```
var rround = "panel-game-"+round;
  var ss = Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel', {
        stateful: true,
        id: "panel-game-"+round,
        stateId: 'stateGrid',
        autoScroll: false,
        store: store,
        columns: [
            {
                text     : 'Teams',
                flex     : 1,
                sortable : true,
                dataIndex: 'team_name'
            }
        ],
        height: 100,
        width: 150,                                                                            
        title: 'Game ' + round,                                                
        viewConfig: {
            stripeRows: true,
            plugins: {
                ptype: 'gridviewdragdrop',
                dragGroup:  [groups],
                dropGroup:  [groups]
            },
            listeners: {
                drop: function(node, data, dropRec, dropPosition,record,store) {
                    var dropOn = dropRec ? ' ' + dropPosition + ' ' + dropRec.get('name') : ' on empty view';
                    var data = this.store.data.items;
                    var sdata = new Array();
                    data.each(function(e){
                        var bleh = {team_id: e.data.team_id, team_name:e.data.team_name};
                        sdata.push(bleh);
                    })                                                                                      


                    removeDupe(sdata,this.store);
                }
            }
        }
    });
```

This is my empty grid that should accept drops and should also drag when there is data in it.

```
 var rCell = Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel', {
    stateful: true,
    id: "panel-game-"+i+'-'+a,
    stateId: 'stateGrid',
    autoScroll: false,
    store: rCellStore,
    columns: [
        {
            text     : 'Teams',
            flex     : 1,
            sortable : true,
            dataIndex: 'team_name'
        }
    ],
    viewConfig: {
        plugins: {
            ptype: 'gridviewdragdrop',
            dragGroup:  [groups],
            dropGroup:  [groups]
        },
        listeners: {
            beforedrop: function(node,data,overModel,dropPosition,eOpts){
                console.log(node);
            },
            drop: function(node, data, dropRec, dropPosition, record) {
                console.log("drop");
                var dropOn = dropRec ? ' ' + dropPosition + ' ' + dropRec.get('title') : ' on empty view';
                var f = node.id.replace('-body','');
                var newval = data.records[0].data;

                if(f != undefined && f != ''){
                    var fstore = Ext.getCmp(f).getStore();
                    fstore.add(newval);
                }

                var data = this.store.data.items;
                var sdata = new Array();
                data.each(function(e){
                    var bleh = {team_id: e.data.team_id, team_name:e.data.team_name};
                    sdata.push(bleh);
                })                                                                                      


                removeDupe(sdata,this.store);


            }
        }
    },
    height: 100,
    width: 150,                                                                            
    title: 'Game ',                                                
    viewConfig: {
        stripeRows: true
    }
});
```

It does not give a dropzone avaliable when i and trying to drag something over. It could be that but im not sure how to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was the second viewConfig{stripeRows:true}. Chrome could figure it out but the other browsers were overwriting the first viewConfig with the second.